# Find all permutations code Problem (Java)

Tags: java, permutation

I wrote this code to find all possible permutations of some numbers. But i dosen't want to use one digit twice:
123,132,213 are OK, but it produces numbers like 122, 121 etc.
What am i doing wrong?

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {        

    HashSet<Integer> l = new HashSet<Integer>();        
    for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
        l.add(i);
    }       
    perm(l,3,new StringBuffer());

}

 static void perm(HashSet<Integer> in, int depth,StringBuffer out){             
    if(depth==0){
        System.out.println(out);
        return;
    }       

    int len = in.size();
    HashSet<Integer> tmp = in;

    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        out.append(in.toArray()[i]);
        tmp.remove(i);

        perm(tmp,depth-1,out);

        out.deleteCharAt(out.length()-1);
        tmp.add(i);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Autoboxing is getting you.  When you call the remove with 'i', My guess is that 'i' has been boxed to a different object and is thus not found in your HashSet.

Comment: Ok, i dont know much about Autoboxing.
I think, the code itself isn't optimal. Could I use an other dada structure than a HashSet?

Comment: @gethan Autoboxing is where Java will convert a primitive type (e.g. int) into the equivilent class (e.g. Integer) or do that process in reverse. So when you first add an int to the HashSet, it gets converted into an object. Lets call that object 'AnInt'. Then when you remove the second int, it gets boxed to an object 'AnotherInt', and those two objects are not the same. Thus the HashSet is not finding the first one to remove.

Answer (score 2):

`tmp.remove(i)` is wrong. You need to remove the ith element from tmp... you are removing the element "i". So, do `tmp.remove(in.toArray()[i])`. I think that will fix this up. For instance, if the zeroth element is 17, doing `tmp.remove(i)` will remove all zeroes from the HashSet, not "17".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much simpler implementation using a HashSet. I'm using strings but the concept remains the same.

```
public void printPermutations(String str){
    HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
    printPermutations("", str, hs);
}

public void printPermutations(String prefix, String end, HashSet<String> hs){
    if(end.equals(""))
        System.out.println(prefix);
    for(int i = 0; i < end.length(); ++i)
        if(hs.add(prefix + end.charAt(i))){
            printPermutations(prefix + end.charAt(i), 
                    end.substring(0,i) + end.substring(i + 1, end.length()), hs);
        }

}
```